# objective c javaScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c

Is it possible for a `NSTextField` to respond to `Javascript` commands??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It only accepts objective-c messages.

If you have a WebView that generates some javascript events though, they can trigger something outside of your web view, but this is already objective-c or some other native language. This can then call obj-c messages on the NSTextField.